# JS how to reject wrapper promise from inside one?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

how to reject wrapper promise from inside one or? in other words, how to make number '3' never printed?
Current output:

```
1
2
3
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
```

```javascript
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log(1)
  resolve()
})
.then(() => console.log(2))
.then(() => { // how to reject this one if internal fails?
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject(new Error('Polling failure'));
  })
  .then(() => console.log(21))
})
.then(() => console.log(3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just missing a `return`

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(1)
    resolve()
  })
  .then(() => console.log(2))
  .then(() => { // how to reject this one if internal fails?
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        reject(new Error('Polling failure'));
      })
      .then(() => console.log(21))
  })
  .then(() => console.log(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to reject a promise chain from a `.then()` handler, you need to either:

#### Use [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Throwing any value will mark the promise as unsuccessful:

```js
const p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log(1)
  resolve()
})
.then(() => console.log(2))
.then(() => { throw new Error(); })
.then(() => console.log(3));


p
  .then(() => console.log("sucessful finish"))
  .catch(() => console.log("error finish"));
```

#### Return a rejected promise

The easiest way is with [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject):

```js
const p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log(1)
  resolve()
})
.then(() => console.log(2))
.then(() => Promise.reject("problem"))
.then(() => console.log(3));


p
  .then(() => console.log("sucessful finish"))
  .catch(() => console.log("error finish"));
```