# Promise chain continues after rejection

Tags: javascript, promise, chain, waterfall, unhandled-promise-rejection

I'm having trouble to properly catch an error/reject in a promise chain.

```js
const p1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("P1");
        resolve();
    });
};

const p2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("P2");
        reject();
    });
};


const p3 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("P3");
        resolve();
    });
};

p1().catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught p1");
}).then(p2).catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught p2");
}).then(p3).catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught p3");
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Final then");
});
```

When the promise is rejected, the following `.then` still gets executed. In my understanding, when in a promise chain an error/reject happened, the `.then` calls that follow it are not executed any more.

```
P1
P2
Caught p2
P3
Final then
```

The rejection gets caught correctly, but why is "P3" logged after the catch?

What am I doing wrong?

To clarify @evolutionxbox, this is my expected result:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log("resolve #1");
    return Promise.reject();
}).then(() => {
    console.log("resolve #2");
    return Promise.resolve();
}).then(() => {
    console.log("resolve #3");
    return Promise.resolve();
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Final end");
}).catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught");
});
```

This code works exactly like it should. And I can't see a difference to my code, except that I declared the functions separately.

The code above stops no matter where the promise is rejected.

Comment: The first `.catch()` after the rejection takes care of the error and after that the default chain is continued.

Comment: @Sirko Thats exactly what happens. But *why*? I thought that the chain is "aborted" on the first reject. How can i stop the execution of the following function on a reject? And why cant i just use a "global" catch for all promises?

Comment: You're calling p3 after you catch the error from p2. The catch handles the error, then proceeds as if it didn't happen

Comment: The return value of `catch` is a promise so it will have a then method right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch why do you think it should stop?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please see my updated question. Because that excatly how chaining should work. See the attached (correct) working example.

Comment: You are just not correct in your assumptions, that's all. .catch doesn't stop promise chain for the same reason regular try .. catch doesn't stop code execution of a code located after catch. It wouldn't make sense if it did

Comment: @Max Ok, makes sense. But why if i remove any other catch block except the last one, i get a "promise rejection" warning in node?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a synchronous equivalent of your code:

```js
const f1 = () => {
  console.log("F1");
};

const f2 = () => {
  console.log("F2");
  throw new Error();
};

const f3 = () => {
  console.log("F3");
};

try {
  f1();
} catch {
  console.log("Caught f1");
}

try {
  f2();
} catch {
  console.log("Caught f2");
}

try {
  f3();
} catch {
  console.log("Caught f3");
}

console.log("Final code");
```

As you can see, that gives a matching result. Hopefully, looking at the synchronous code you would not be surprised why. In a [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) you are allowed to attempt recovery. The idea is that the `catch` will *stop* the error propagation and you can hopefully continue further. Or if you do want to stop, you still have to explicitly `throw` again, for example:

```
doCode();

try {
    makeCoffee();
} catch(err) {
    if (err instanceof IAmATeapotError) {
        //attempt recovery
        makeTea();
    } else {
        //unrecoverable - log and re-throw
        console.error("Fatal coffee related issue encountered", err);
        throw err;
    }
}

doCode();
```

This is also the purpose [`Promise#catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) serves - so you can attempt recovery or at least act when there was a problem. The idea is that *after* the `.catch()` you might be able to continue:

```js
const orderPizza = (topping) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (topping === "pepperoni")
      reject(new Error("No pepperoni available"));
    else
      resolve(`${topping} pizza`);
  });

const makeToast = () => "toast";
const eat = food => console.log(`eating some ${food}`);

async function main() {
  await orderPizza("cheese")
    .catch(makeToast)
    .then(eat);
    
  console.log("-----");
  
  await orderPizza("pepperoni")
    .catch(makeToast)
    .then(eat);
}

main();
```

In order to reject the promise chain from a `.catch()` you need to do something similar as a normal `catch` and *fail* at the error recovery by inducing another error. [You can `throw` or return a rejected promise to that effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65942006/).

> This code works exactly like it should. And I can't see a difference to my code, except that I declared the functions separately.
>
> The code above stops no matter where the promise is rejected.

The second piece of code you show fails entirely after a reject because there are no other `.catch()`-es that are successful. It is basically similar to this synchronous code:

```js
try {
    console.log("log #1");
    throw new Error();
    console.log("log #2");
    console.log("log #3");
    console.log("Final end");
} catch {
    console.log("Caught");
}
```

Thus if you *do not* want to recover early, you can also skip the `.catch()` instead of inducing another error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
const p1 = (arg) => {
  // Promise returns data in the respected arguments
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Data to be accessed through first argument.
    resolve(arg);

  });
};


const p2 = (arg) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Data to be accessed through second argument.
    reject(arg);

  });
}

p1('p1').then(resolve => {
  console.log(resolve + ' is handled with the resolve argument. So it is accessed with .then()');
}) // Since reject isn't configured to pass any data we don't use .catch()

p2('p2').catch(reject => {
  console.log(reject + ' is handled with the reject argument. So it is accessed with .catch()');
}) // Since resolve ins't configured to pass any data we don't use .then()

// You would normally configure a Promise to return a value on with resolve, and access it with .then() when it completes a task successfully.

// .catch() would then be chained on to the end of .then() to handle errors when a task cannot be completed.

// Here is an example.

const p3 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var condition = true;

    if (condition === true) {
      resolve('P3');
    } else {
      reject('Promise failed!');
    }

  });
};

p3('p3').then(resolve => {
  console.log(resolve);
}).catch(reject => {
  console.log(reject);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not do anything wrong.
In your code you call the first promise **p1**. Then you write `p1.catch(...).then(...).then(...).then(...)`. This is a chain which means that you should call `then` 3 times, because you called resolve method in the **p1** promise (all these `then`s depend on the first promise).

Comment: That was not my question. Why is the chain not "aborted" if i reject a promisie. The rest is still executed. I updated my question, with a working example of how my code should work.

Answer (score 0):

> When the promise is rejected, the following `.then` still gets executed.

Yes. Just to be accurate: the `then` and `catch` method calls are all executed synchronously (in one go), and so all promises involved are created in one go. It's the *callbacks* passed to these methods that execute asynchronously, as the relevant promises resolve (fullfill or reject).

> In my understanding, when in a promise chain an error/reject happened, the `.then` calls that follow it are not executed any more.

This is not the case. The promise that a `catch` returns can either fullfill or reject *depending* on what happens in the callback passed to it, and so the callbacks further down the chain will execute accordingly when that promise resolves.

> The rejection gets caught correctly, but why is "P3" logged after the catch?

As in your case the `catch` callback returns `undefined` (it only performs a `console.log`), its promise *fullfulls*! By consequence, the chained `then` callback -- on *that* promise -- is executed... etc.

### If you want to "stop"

If you want to keep the chain as it is, but wish to have a behaviour where a rejection leads to no further execution of `then` or `catch` callbacks, then don't resolve the associated promise:

```js
const stop = new Promise(resolve => null);

const p1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("P1");
        resolve();
    });
};

const p2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("P2");
        reject();
    });
};


const p3 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("P3");
        resolve();
    });
};

p1().catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught p1");
    return stop; // don't resolve
}).then(p2).catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught p2");
    return stop;
}).then(p3).catch(() => {
    console.log("Caught p3");
    return stop;
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Final then");
});
```

Comment: `new Promise(resolve => null)` will just halt the entire promise chain. I'm not sure that's a very good idea, as it makes any sort of recovery later impossible. Even something like attaching a `.finally()` is not going to be processed. I'd suggest either not attaching a `.catch()` if no recovery attempt should be made because knowing a promise chain failed is usually more valuable than just leaving it in limbo forever. An alternative is to reject from within the `.catch()` either by throwing an error or returning a rejected promise. That still fails the rest of the chain.

Comment: Indeed it halts the entire promise chain. That was my understanding of the OP's wishes. I would never do this myself, but then I also don't want things to halt like that.